# c#-adding a ASP:Button in the back code

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hi it just so happens that I have to need this kind of approach (or any suggestion if you have)
this code produce table

```
while (rd.Read())
{
    resultsHtml.Append("<tr class='odd gradeX'>");
    resultsHtml.Append("<td>" + rd["region_location"].ToString() + "</td>");
    resultsHtml.Append("<td>" + rd["region_tag"].ToString() + "</td>");
    resultsHtml.Append("<td class='center'>");
    resultsHtml.Append("<div class='tooltip-demo'>");
    resultsHtml.Append("<a class='btn btn-info' href='regionEdit.aspx?id=" + rd["region_id"].ToString() + "'><i class='fa fa-paw'></i></a> ");
    resultsHtml.Append("<asp:Button ID='btnDelete' runat='server' Text='Login' CssClass='btn btn-outline btn-primary' Style='width: 100px;' OnClick='btnDelete_Click' />");
    resultsHtml.Append("</div>");
    resultsHtml.Append("</td>");
    resultsHtml.Append("</tr>");
}
```

if you will notice there is an `asp:button` there. because i want that if the user clicks that button, it will just delete it. So I put an

```
  public void btnSubmitDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
}
```

but the things is. It is not displaying and I can't figure out how to put the `region_id` in the `asp:button` to determine which is which to delete and every loop of the while. Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think when u want to add an asp control and show that control to end user u should add dynamically control to a placeholder or panel like this code :

```
        <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="_plchControles"></asp:PlaceHolder>
```

and in code bihind :

```
        var btn = new System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button();
        btn.Text = "sample";
        btn.ID = "btnSubmitDelete";
        btn.OnClientClick += btnSubmitDelete_Click;
        _plchContent.Controls.Add(btn);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your script will work as HTML control and you can bind click event from Javascript. To do so define a WebMethod in c# and call it from Javascript click event.
e.g.

```
$("#btnDelete").on("click",function(e)
{
     var para=[]
     para.param1=val1;
     para.param2=val2;
     $.post("/path/delete",para,function(result)
    {

    });
});
```

C#

```
[WebMethod]
public void delete(string param1,string param2)
{
   //Delete code here
}
```

else 
**mohammadreza izadi**  answers will work if you want to asp.net control but you have to make object of button as defined not string.